# Is there a difference in how tf.nn.softmax() performs in TF versions 2.3.1 and 2.4.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running `tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()` on two instances with the different TF versions (once 2.3.1 and once 2.4.0) and am getting different outputs for each.

tf_output being [1.9530067 1.2070574] on both instances while the instance with version 2.4.0 returns `[0.67829543 0.32170454]` and the one with version 2.3.1 returns `[[1. 1.]]`.

The only other main difference between the two machines is that one is running TF with GPU support (the one with version 2.4.1), the other one is a VM and doesn't have a GPU included, only two vCPUs.
Everything else should be exactly equal on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alxgal,
I tested this code at both 2.4 and 2.3.1 and got same result. Most likely you somehow altered the input vector dimensions in one of the tests (like entered extra set of brackets). See example below:

```
a = tf.constant([1.9530067, 1.2070574])
print(a.shape, tf.nn.softmax(a, axis=0).numpy())
b = tf.constant([[1.9530067, 1.2070574]])
print(b.shape, tf.nn.softmax(b, axis=0).numpy())

(2,) [0.67829543 0.32170454]
(1, 2) [[1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for testing this! I marked your answer as accepted as it answers my question here. My issue persists though. It seems like it's not related to the different versions of tf then.

Comment: check the dimensions of your input. Print the data  or dimensions explicitly, before calling `softmax`. See if it is different.

Comment: EDIT: It seems like my initial processing of tf_output didn't behave the same way in the instance that ran tf version 2.3.1 as it did in the instance with version 2.4.0.
So you were right, the input wasn't the same, but the behavior was still unnexpected in my usecase.
Thank so much for the help again!